# Forcycle ifs with objects in java

Tags: java

basicly i am doing my school project and i found out that forcycling the code below isnť that easy as i thought, so i am asking you for solutions thanks.

```
                if (hrac.getBoundsInParent().intersects(vlna.get(0).getBoundsInParent())) {
                    vymaz();
                }
                if (hrac.getBoundsInParent().intersects(vlna.get(1).getBoundsInParent())) {
                    vymaz();
                }
                if (hrac.getBoundsInParent().intersects(vlna.get(2).getBoundsInParent())) {
                    vymaz();
                }
                if (hrac.getBoundsInParent().intersects(vlna.get(3).getBoundsInParent())) {
                    vymaz();
                }
                if (hrac.getBoundsInParent().intersects(vlna.get(4).getBoundsInParent())) {
                    vymaz();
                }
                if (hrac.getBoundsInParent().intersects(vlna.get(5).getBoundsInParent())) {
                    vymaz();
                }
```

Comment: Welcome! It would be helpful to define 'forcycling'. I did a web search, but couldn't find any good definition.

Comment: Sorry i am not best english speaker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A simple `for-i loop` like :

   ```
   for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
       if (hrac.getBoundsInParent().intersects(vlna.get(i).getBoundsInParent())) {
          vymaz();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Using `IntStream` :

   ```
   IntStream.range(0, 6)
       .filter(i -> hrac.getBoundsInParent().intersects(vlna.get(i).getBoundsInParent()))
       .forEach(i -> vymaz());
   ```